# Get the name of Current User

Tags: user-profile

I can get the ID of the current user with this command:

```
$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser().toString();
```

Is there a way to get the NAME of the current user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
currentName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({ fieldName: "Title", debug: false });
```